How to display Size property in form of "number+units" in the custom operator's REDO panel?
If we add some standard mesh (e.g, cube) - the Size property will be displayed as
number + units :

API documentation says that in case of primitive_cube_add the Size property is:

float in [0, inf]

___
Ok, let's make a custom operator, which contains Size FloatProperty
In this case no units mentioned,
just a number :


The question :
How can I display Size property in form of number + units ?


bpy.props.FloatProperty has unit and subtype can input.

@XY - tried unit:  it's EXACTLY what I needed. Huge thanks for help! ❤️

@XY has answered my question in the comments, but for some reason hasn't posted it as a full answer.
So, here is the solution (kudos to XY) :
FloatProperty (as any other property) has multiple parameters: default, min, max, and many others.
One of these parameters is unit.
By default unit has value "NONE", but if we set it to "LENGTH" distance units will be displayed:

meters
inches
etc. (depending on the scene's unit settings)


Example of code:
size:FloatProperty(
     name='Size',
     unit='LENGTH',
     precision=3,
     default=1,
     min=0) 


NOTE: unit can be not only "LENGTH", but also "ROTATION", "VELOCITY" and many others.
Every possible type of unit is described HERE
